# Publish from RStudio to local Shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I can't seem to find instructions on how to deploy my Shiny app from RStudio to my local Shiny server (not to ShinyApps). The Shiny server is working fine with the sample apps. When I click the RStudio 'Publish Application...' button and the 'Add New Account' the only option is to set up to publish to ShinyApps.

I've looked under http://shiny.rstudio.com/deploy/ but can't seem to see anything.

Help anyone?

Comment: Question asking for tutorial are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

OK, apparently you can't publish to a local server from RStudio. This functionality is coming though.

Comment: I'm looking into the same thing now, and found this question. Anyone know if the functionality has arrived ~5 year later?

Answer (score -2):

Install related library in r from terminal then copy your shiny apps to /srv/shiny-server/   folder then from browser access those  -- give_address 127.0.0.1:3838/ then go.
magic will happen and you will see your shiny app get locally hosted for sharing to your organisation turn off firewall and give link as below
 :3838/
for each shiny app need to create separate directory with app name and make changes in link

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.